# ReadAsync is emptying stream

Tags: c#, sockets, cryptostream

So, I had this code working fine for communication between a client/server program. The communication is done with one byte buffer that has two elements, an int that specifies how many bytes follow, and the "payload". If I use my 
debugger to step through and check. When my code reaches the line

`await cStream.ReadAsync(bytes, 0, 4)`;

If I check the amount of bytes available, it says 32. Once I step passed this line it says bytes available is 0. If I read directly from _stream (my TcpClient's NetworkStream) then the code works just fine.

The full code is

```
private async void RecvAsync()
{

    byte[]          key     = { 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08, 0x09, 0x10, 0x11, 0x12, 0x13, 0x14, 0x15, 0x16 };
    byte[]          iv      = { 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08, 0x09, 0x10, 0x11, 0x12, 0x13, 0x14, 0x15, 0x16 };
    RijndaelManaged crypto  = new RijndaelManaged();
    CryptoStream    cStream = new CryptoStream(_stream, crypto.CreateDecryptor(key, iv), CryptoStreamMode.Read);

    int bytesRead = 0;

    do
    {
        try
        {
            byte[] bytes = new byte[4];
            await cStream.ReadAsync( bytes, 0, 4 );
            //await _stream.ReadAsync(bytes, 0, 4, _cancelToken.Token);

            int size = BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes, 0);


            cStream = new CryptoStream(_stream, crypto.CreateDecryptor(key, iv), CryptoStreamMode.Read);
            bytes = new byte[size];
            bytesRead = cStream.Read( bytes, 0, size );
            //await _stream.ReadAsync(bytes, 0, bytes.Length, _cancelToken.Token); //_stream.Read( bytes, 0, size );

            int id   = BitConverter.ToInt32( bytes, 0 );
            int type = BitConverter.ToInt32( bytes, 4 );

            UTF8Encoding utf  = new UTF8Encoding();
            string       body = utf.GetString( bytes, 8, size - 8 );

            Packet packet = new Packet( id, (ServerDataType)type, body );
            ProcessPacket( packet );
        }
        catch ( Exception ) { break; }
    } while ( bytesRead > 0 );
}
```

Comment: The two commented lines of code are where I previously read directly from the NetworkStream without encryption and it works without a hitch using those two lines instead of encryption.

Comment: CryptoStream assumes that all data in the wrapped stream is going to be processed, so it reads in bigger chunks for efficiency. If you need to control it you need to make a stream wrapper that throttles. But note it will always have to read multiples of the transform’s input block size.

Comment: Do you know what a TCP keep-alive message is?  It is a datagram with zero bytes that is used to prevent servers from closing an idle channel.  The correct way of sending binary data is to precede the message with a byte count and read until all the bytes are read.  TCP will fragment message into datagrams which has max size ~1500 bytes.  You must design to handle the fragmentation.  Reading one byte at a time is not very efficient.

Comment: @bartonjs So I have to read the entire available buffer and parse from that?

Comment: @jdweng That's exactly what I've done, I read one integer, that integer tells the length of the rest of the data, then I read as many bytes as that data says to read.

Comment: Essentially, you can’t read a stream again after you give it to a CryptoStream. That may mean custom buffering, or it may mean you want to switch to using SslStream and let things get “just handled” for you.

Comment: Just realized something. In the code I posted, I set cStream to the same thing a second time. I did that just as a test to see what happens.

Comment: The read of the size should be before the while loop.  If you are sending a message of 1 million bytes, you are going to get the message in chunks of 1500 byte datagrams. The size will be 1 million and is gong to get overridden each time through the while loop..   Also if you are getting a message larger than an integer size you should use 8 bytes and a long.

Comment: @jdwent I think you're not understanding my code a bit. In the loop, it hits the first ReadAsync to read the length of the following data. Then reads the data based on that number. Then it constructs a "Packet" class that I've created. Then it does the loop again so when it hits the first ReadAsync, it patiently awaits the next packet to be sent to it.

Comment: @jdweng Forgot to mention in my last comment. My packet sizes are between 20 and 300 bytes.

Comment: Still do not assume you will get the 20 to 300 bytes in one receive message.  TCP and windows can split messages into smaller pieces and you may get more than one send message in one receive message.

Comment: @jdweng First I'm just trying to get "read 4" to mean "read 4" instead of "read 4 and throw away the other 34" (The test message is 38 bytes). I just removed the encryption and replaced it with networkstream.ReadAsync. Does exactly what I need it to do again. Just, without encryption, lol.

Answer (score 0):

Try following code :

```
        private async void RecvAsync()
        {

            byte[]          key     = { 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08, 0x09, 0x10, 0x11, 0x12, 0x13, 0x14, 0x15, 0x16 };
            byte[]          iv      = { 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08, 0x09, 0x10, 0x11, 0x12, 0x13, 0x14, 0x15, 0x16 };
            RijndaelManaged crypto  = new RijndaelManaged();
            CryptoStream    cStream = new CryptoStream(_stream, crypto.CreateDecryptor(key, iv), CryptoStreamMode.Read);

            int bytesRead = 0;

            byte[] bytes = new byte[8];
            List<byte> buffer = new List<byte>();
            cStream.Read( bytes, 0, 4 );
            //await _stream.ReadAsync(bytes, 0, 4, _cancelToken.Token);
            int size = BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes, 0);

            do
            {
                bytesRead = cStream.Read( bytes, 0, 8 );

                buffer.AddRange(bytes.Take(bytesRead));

            } while ( buffer.Count() < size );
            try
            {

                if(buffer.Count() >= 8)
                {

                    int id   = BitConverter.ToInt32( buffer.ToArray(), 0 );
                    int type = BitConverter.ToInt32( buffer.ToArray(), 4 );

                    UTF8Encoding utf  = new UTF8Encoding();
                    string  body = utf.GetString( buffer.ToArray(), 8, size - 8 );

                    Packet packet = new Packet( id, (ServerDataType)type, body );
                    ProcessPacket( packet );
                }
            }
            catch ( Exception ) { break; }
        }
```

Comment: I actually came across a different solution that I think I can adapt to my needs.